# R Dynamic split/subset of dataframe by selected rownumbers- Parsing textgrid praat

Tags: r, data-structures, split, subset, praat

I am trying to process a "segmentation file" called `.TextGrid` (generated by Praat program). )

The original format  looks like this:

```
File type = "ooTextFile"
Object class = "TextGrid"
xmin = 0 
xmax = 243.761375 
tiers? <exists> 
size = 17 
item []: 
    item [1]:
        class = "IntervalTier" 
        name = "phones" 
        xmin = 0 
        xmax = 243.761 
        intervals: size = 2505 
        intervals [1]:
            xmin = 0 
            xmax = 0.4274939687384032 
            text = "_" 
        intervals [2]:
            xmin = 0.4274939687384032 
            xmax = 0.472 
            text = "v" 
        intervals [3]:
[...]
```

(This is then repeted to EOF, with intervals[3 to n] for n Item (layer of annotation) in a file.

Somebody [proposed a solution](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/textgrid.py)  using [rPython R package](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/).

Unfortunately :

- I don't have a good knowledge of Python
- **The version of rPython is not available for R.3.0.2** (which I am using).
- My aim is to develop this parser for my analysis exclusively under R environment.

---

Right now my aim is to segment this file into multiple data frame. Each dataframe should contain one item (layer of annotation).

```
# Load the Data
txtgrid <- read.delim("./xxx_01_xx.textgrid", sep=c("=","\n"), dec=".", header=FALSE)
# Erase White spaces (use stringr package)
txtgrid[,1] <- str_trim(txtgrid[,1])
# Convert row.names to numeric 
num.row<- as.numeric(row.names(txtgrid))
# Redefine the original textgrid and add those rows (I want to "keep them in case for later process)
txtgrid <- data.frame(num.row,txtgrid)
colnames(txtgrid) <- c("num.row","object", "value")
head(txtgrid)
```

The output of `head(txtgrid)` is very raw, so here is the first 20 lines of the textgrid `txtgrid[1:20,]`:

```
   num.row          object                value
1        1       File type           ooTextFile
2        2    Object class             TextGrid
3        3            xmin                   0 
4        4            xmax          243.761375 
5        5 tiers? <exists>                     
6        6            size                  17 
7        7        item []:                     
8        8       item [1]:                     
9        9           class        IntervalTier 
10      10            name              phones 
11      11            xmin                   0 
12      12            xmax             243.761 
13      13 intervals: size                2505 
14      14  intervals [1]:                     
15      15            xmin                   0 
16      16            xmax  0.4274939687384032 
17      17            text                   _ 
18      18  intervals [2]:                     
19      19            xmin  0.4274939687384032 
20      20            xmax               0.472
```

Now that I pre-processed it, I can :

```
# Find the number of the rows where I want to split (i.e. Item)
tier.begining <- txtgrid[grep("item", txtgrid$object, perl=TRUE), ]
# And save those numbers in a variable
x <- as.numeric(row.names(tier.begining))
```

This variable `x` gives me the numbers-1 where my Data should be splitted in several dataframes.

I have 18 items -1 (the first item is item[] and include all the other items. So vector `x` is :

```
     x
    [1]     7     8 10034 14624 19214 22444 25674 28904 31910 35140 38146 38156 38566 39040 39778 40222 44800
[18] 45018
```

**How can I tell to R** : to segment this dataframe in multiple dataframes `textgrids$nameoftheItem` in such a way that I get as many data frame as I have of items?, for example :

```
textgrid$phones
         item [1]:
            class = "IntervalTier" 
            name = "phones" 
            xmin = 0 
            xmax = 243.761 
            intervals: size = 2505 
            intervals [1]:
            xmin = 0 
            xmax = 0.4274939687384032 
            text = "_" 
            intervals [2]:
            xmin = 0.4274939687384032 
            xmax = 0.472 
            text = "v" 
            [...]
            intervals [n]:
textgrid$syllable
    item [2]:
            class = "IntervalTier" 
            name = "syllable" 
            xmin = 0 
            xmax = 243.761 
            intervals: size = 1200
            intervals [1]:
            xmin = 0 
            xmax = 0.500
            text = "ve" 
            intervals [2]:
            [...]
            intervals [n]:
    textgrid$item[n]
```

---

I wanted to use

```
txtgrid.new <- split(txtgrid, f=x)
```

But this message is right :

```
Warning message: In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

I don't get the desired outputed, it seems that row numbers don't follow each other and that the file is all mixed up.

I have also tried some `which`, `daply`  (from `plyr`) & `subset` functions but never got them to work properly!

I am welcoming any idea to structure this data properly & efficiently. Ideally I should be able to link items (layers of annotation) between them (xmin & xmax of different layers), as well as multiple textgrid files, this is just the beginning.

Comment: Your input file looks suspiciously like `JSON`. You could look at the `rjson` package and see if it will read in the file for you?

Comment: Can you please include the output of `head(txtgrid)`?

Comment: JSON proposition doesn't seem much more accessible to me than parsing it for myself (i need to be able to manipulate by myself these objects afterwards anyway..., for the moment I can't seem to make JSON work, but thanks for the proposition). @jbaums : done, added this output (which is not very informative, but gives an idea of how to access the data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the `split` vector should be equal to the number of rows in the `data.frame`.

Try the following:

```
txtgrid.sub <- txtgrid[-(1:grep("item", txtgrid$object)[1]), ]

grep("item", txtgrid.sub$object)[-1]

splits <- unlist(mapply(rep, seq_along(grep("item", txtgrid.sub$object)),
                        diff(c(grep("item", txtgrid.sub$object), 
                               nrow(txtgrid.sub) + 1))))

df.list <- split(txtgrid.sub, list(splits))
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could then simplify the data by doing something like this:

```
l <- lapply(df.list, function(x) {
  tmp <- as.data.frame(t(x[, 3, drop=FALSE]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(tmp) <- make.unique(make.names(x[, 2]))
  tmp
})

library(plyr)
do.call(rbind.fill, l)


  item..1..        class     name xmin    xmax intervals..size
1      <NA> IntervalTier   phones    0 243.761            2505
2      <NA> IntervalTier syllable    0 243.761            2505
  intervals..1.. xmin.1             xmax.1 text intervals..2..
1           <NA>      0 0.4274939687384032    _           <NA>
2           <NA>      0 0.4274939687384032    _           <NA>
              xmin.2 xmax.2
1 0.4274939687384032  0.472
2               <NA>   <NA>
```

NB: I've used dummy data for the above.

Comment: __This Answer is Useful.__ I can access my tiers by `new.df[[1]]` for phones and `new.df[[n]]` for n=number of the designated tier. I should apply interval for tuple `tier`xmin-xmax-text` pretty easily from here (reshape in one dataframe with some `t()`. And i will implement the calling automatically by `layer.name` If anyone wish any update don't hesitate to send me a message.

Comment: Note, I changed the name of the resulting object from `new.df` to `df.list`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found a good solution elsewhere, but I thought I might as well put this here for reference:

I recently finished a first working version of a JSON converter for Praat objects that could have been used for this. You can save the TextGrid as a JSON file using the script `save_as_json.praat` included in [this plugin](https://github.com/jjatria/plugin_jjatools) (again: I am the author of that plugin).

Copied from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823643/807650) to a similar question, once you have the plugin installed you can use the script from the `Save` menu in Praat or run it like this from another script:

```
runScript: preferencesDirectory$ + "/plugin_jjatools/save_as_json.praat",
  ..."/output/path", "Pretty printed"
```

Once that is done, you can read it into `R` using `rjson` like this:

```
> library(rjson)
> tg <- fromJSON(file='/path/to/your_textgrid.json')
> str(tg)
List of 5
$ File type   : chr "json"
$ Object class: chr "TextGrid"
$ start       : num 0
$ end         : num 1.82
$ tiers       :List of 2
    ..$ :List of 5
    .. ..$ class    : chr "IntervalTier"
    .. ..$ name     : chr "keyword"
    .. ..$ start    : num 0
    .. ..$ end      : num 1.82
    .. ..$ intervals:List of 3
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 0
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 0.995
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr ""
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 0.995
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.5
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "limite"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.5
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.82
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr ""
    ..$ :List of 5
    .. ..$ class    : chr "IntervalTier"
    .. ..$ name     : chr "segments"
    .. ..$ start    : num 0
    .. ..$ end      : num 1.82
    .. ..$ intervals:List of 8
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 0
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 0.995
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr ""
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 0.995
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.07
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "l"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.07
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.15
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "i"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.15
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.23
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "m"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.23
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.28
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "i"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.28
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.37
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "t"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.37
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.5
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr "e"
    .. .. ..$ :List of 3
    .. .. .. ..$ start: num 1.5
    .. .. .. ..$ end  : num 1.82
    .. .. .. ..$ label: chr ""
```

Or using, for example, `tg$tiers[[tier_number]]$intervals[[interval_number]]`.